# Creating a Thunderbird addon to move a mail into a folder

Tags: thunderbird

I want ot create a button in Thunderbird to move selected emails into a folder.
With this example it was easy to create a button:
https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/mailextensions/hello-world-add-on
But how can I add the logic into the background.js to move a mail?

In my former plugin, that is not supported any more with Thunderbirg 78, I could use this js code:

```
var targetUri = "mailbox://nobody@Local%20Folders/Inbox/backlog";
var targetFolder =  MailUtils.getFolderForURI(targetUri);
MsgMoveMessage(targetFolder);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but this seems to be exactly what the [`message.move()`](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messages.html#move-messageids-destination) API is for.

Here is the method's description:

> `move(messageIds, destination)`
>
> Moves messages to a specified folder.
>
> - `messageIds` (array of integer) The IDs of the messages to move.
> - `destination` (MailFolder) The folder to move the messages to.

It looks easy to get IDs for the displayed messages with `messageDisplay.getDisplayedMessages()`, or you can use `messages.query()` to get the messages you want, however I'm unsure whether the API currently provides a way to get IDs for the message you would *select* from the message list.